# Query to return total non-overlapping time of an events within a video

Tags: sql, oracle

I have gathered data for certain events that happen within a video. I need to figure out the total time that any event occurred within that video, but I cannot double count periods where there are multiple events happening simultaneously. This image below demonstrates the situation.

[image]

In this scenario, there are 4 events which take up 7 seconds of the entire 10 second video. Simply summing the total time of each event incorrectly yields `3 + 2 + 3 + 2 = 10 out of 10 seconds`. The table I'm working in has:

```
video_id, video_length, event_id, event_start, event_end
```

Does anyone know how I can write a query to result the result I'm looking for

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a gaps and islands problem.  Basically, you need to find groups of overlapping records.  You can do this by identifying the first record when something starts.  Then a group is the sum of such flags.

The following finds each "island" with the start and end time, assuming that two events don't start at the same time.

```
select video_id, min(event_start) as event_start, max(event_end) as event_end
from (select e.*,
             sum(IsNotOverlap) over (partition by video_id order by event_start) as grp
      from (select e.*,
                   (case when exists (select 1 from events e2 where e2.event_start < e.event_start and e2.event_end > e.event_start and e2.video_id = v.video_id)
                         then 0 else 1
                    end) as IsNotOverlap
            from events e
           ) e
      ) e
group by video_id, grp;
```

You can use this as a subquery or CTE to get the total time for a given video.

Answer (score 0):

This works even if two events have the same start date, end date or even if one event is completely contained in another:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE videos ( video_id, video_length, event_id, event_start, event_end ) AS
SELECT 1, 10, 1, 1, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 10, 2, 1, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Same start date
SELECT 1, 10, 3, 2, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Same end date
SELECT 1, 10, 4, 3, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 10, 5, 7, 9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 10, 6, 8, 8.5 FROM DUAL;        -- Contained in previous event
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT video_id,
       SUM( event_duration ) AS event_duration,
       MAX( video_length ) AS video_length
FROM   (
  SELECT video_id,
         video_length,
         end_date
           - LAST_VALUE( start_date ) IGNORE NULLS
               OVER ( PARTITION BY video_id
                      ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS event_duration
  FROM   (
    SELECT video_id,
           video_length,
           CASE WHEN 1 = lvl
                AND  1 = SUM( lvl ) OVER ( PARTITION BY video_id
                                           ORDER BY event_date, lvl DESC, ROWNUM )
                THEN event_date
                END AS start_date,
           CASE WHEN 0 = SUM( lvl ) OVER ( PARTITION BY video_id
                                           ORDER BY event_date, lvl DESC, ROWNUM )
                THEN event_date
                END AS end_date
    FROM   videos
    UNPIVOT ( event_date FOR lvl IN ( event_start AS 1, event_end AS -1 ) )
  )
)
GROUP BY video_id;
```

**Output**:

```
  VIDEO_ID EVENT_DURATION VIDEO_LENGTH
---------- -------------- ------------
         1              7           10
```

Answer (score 0):

Variant 1 Complicated:
(Always partition by video_id, order by start_date.) First get running MAX from end_date, then compare event start with the max from previous record. When start <= running max end_date there is an overlapping. Then we are using running sum to make groups of overlapping intervals and at last we are grouping on this groups.

```
  SELECT video_id, video_length, SUM (new_end - new_start) total_time
    FROM (  SELECT video_id, video_length, MIN (event_start) new_start, MAX (new_end) new_end
              FROM (SELECT b.*, SUM (counting) OVER (PARTITION BY video_id ORDER BY event_start) time_group
                      FROM (SELECT a.*, CASE WHEN LAG (new_end, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY video_id ORDER BY event_start) >= event_start THEN NULL ELSE 1 END counting
                              FROM (SELECT x.*, MAX (event_end) OVER (PARTITION BY video_id ORDER BY event_start) new_end
                                      FROM videos x) a) b) c
          GROUP BY video_id, video_length, time_group)
GROUP BY video_id, video_length
ORDER BY video_id
```

Variant 2: Get the start and end of overlapping periods (or of the same period), get only distinct values and sum the time:

```
  SELECT video_id, SUM (new_end - new_start) total_time
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT a.video_id,
                          (SELECT MIN (event_start)
                             FROM videos b
                            WHERE ( (a.event_start BETWEEN b.event_start AND b.event_end) OR (a.event_end BETWEEN b.event_start AND b.event_end)) AND a.video_id = b.video_id)
                             new_start,
                          (SELECT MAX (event_end)
                             FROM videos b
                            WHERE ( (a.event_start BETWEEN b.event_start AND b.event_end) OR (a.event_end BETWEEN b.event_start AND b.event_end)) AND a.video_id = b.video_id)
                             new_end
            FROM videos a)
GROUP BY video_id
```

Variant 3: It is  Variant 2, but modified to use a new feature in Oracle 12 [LATERAL Inline Views](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/lateral-inline-views-cross-apply-and-outer-apply-joins-12cr1#lateral-inline-views)

```
  SELECT video_id, SUM (new_end - new_start) total_time
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT a.video_id, b.new_start, b.new_end
            FROM videos a,
                 LATERAL (SELECT MIN (event_start) new_start, MAX (event_end) new_end
                            FROM videos b
                           WHERE ( (a.event_start BETWEEN b.event_start AND b.event_end) OR (a.event_end BETWEEN b.event_start AND b.event_end)) AND a.video_id = b.video_id) b)
GROUP BY video_id
```

You can use the [CROSS APPLY Join](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/lateral-inline-views-cross-apply-and-outer-apply-joins-12cr1#cross-apply-join) or [OUTER APPLY Join](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/lateral-inline-views-cross-apply-and-outer-apply-joins-12cr1#outer-apply-join) too, which give the same result, because the subquery always returns one row.